# Smooth Streaming SDK for Windows 8 - Error with Headphones Plugged

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, smooth-streaming-player

I'm doing some tests with the Smooth Streaming Client SDK for Windows 8, and I have a very basic application playing a fullscreen video:

```
private MediaExtensionManager extensions = new MediaExtensionManager();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
extensions.RegisterByteStreamHandler("Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.SmoothByteStreamHandler", ".ism", "text/xml");
extensions.RegisterByteStreamHandler("Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.SmoothByteStreamHandler", ".ism", "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml");
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string url = "http://my.smooth.streaming.url/manifest";
    this.slPlayer.Source = new Uri(url);
    this.slPlayer.Play();
}
```

This seems to be working fine, unless I plug my headphones, at which point the application stops working. Adding a handler for the MediaFailed event informs I'm getting a MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED error.

Any idea what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Badaro, I just tried this and was not able to repro the problem (on both x86 & x64, both starting with and without headphones and switching during playback). My guess is that you are either:
1) running into a driver issue.
2) there is something specific about the way your stream is encoded that causes this.

I suggest ruling out #1 by trying on a few different machines.
or, rule out #2 by trying the sample smooth SDK stream: http://mediadl.microsoft.com/mediadl/iisnet/smoothmedia/Experience/BigBuckBunny_720p.ism/Manifest

Comment: Don't have another Win8 machine to test right now, but after doing more tests I'm leaning towards "bizzare driver issue". I'll accept this answer for now, and I'll update if I find something else.